# Why can't I see the background image in front or side views?

Tags: 3d-view, image

I've been not using Blender for quite a while and just came back. I have pressed Number 1 and 3 on the keypad for front and side view but they are not working properly. Properly by which I mean, it's not showing the background images.

[image]

[image]

Did I screw up with the settings somehow?

Comment: Background images can only be seen in **Orthographic View**. You're in *Perspective View*. Press `Num5`.

Comment: @PaulGonet Thank you so much and sorry for the stupid question! :D

Comment: Background images work only in the **Preset Ortho** Views (Front, Back, Left, Right, Top, Bottom) or **Camera Perspective**. No other view will display them.